# Listing unique M2M objects

Tags: python, django

I've got a `Person` model with a `ManyToMany` to `Tags`.
I'm trying to get all combinations of tags, and list the persons that have these tags **uniquely**.

E.g.:

```
Tags a b c d
Person 1 has tags a and b
Person 2 has tags a
Person 3 has tags c
Person 4 has tags a b and c
```

What I want to get to is something like:

```
Tag A: Person 2
Tag B: None
Tag C: Person 3
Tag D: None
Tags [A, B]: Person 1
Tags [A, C]: None
Tags [A, D]: None
Tags [B, C]: None
Tags [B, D]: None
Tags [C, D]: None
Tags [A, B, C]: Person 4
Tags [A, B, D]: None
(etc.)
```

With `itertools.combinations` I'm able to iterate all tags, like:

```
for L in range(0, len(tag_list)+1):
    for tag_combination in combinations(tag_list, L):
        print(Person.objects.filter(tag__name__in=tag_list))
```

But the problem with the above (in the `print()` statement) is that Person 4 would pop up in "Tag A", "Tag B", Tag C", "Tag [A, B]", "Tag [A, C]", "Tag [B, C]", "Tag [B, D]", "Tag [C, D]", "Tag [A, B, C]", etc., while I only want this person to be listed under "Tags [A, B, C]".

Any idea how to best approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the M2M table directly and build a mapping between people and tags:

```
from collections import defaultdict

people_to_tags = defaultdict(list)

for tag_id, person_id in Person.tags.through.objects.all().values_list('tag_id', 'person_id'):
    people_to_tags[person_id].append(tag_id)
```

Then, just invert the mapping:

```
tags_to_people = defaultdict(list)

for person_id, tags in people_to_tags.items():
    tags_to_people[tuple(tags)].append(person_id)
```

You only want the rows where the number of people is 1:

```
tag_to_person = {tag_id: people[0] for tag_id, people in tags_to_people.items() if len(people) == 1}
```